# .htaccess 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Whenever I apply .htaccess file in my WAMP servers `www` folder, it shows:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please
>   contact the server administrator, webmaster@http://www.domain.com
>   and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error. More information about this
>   error may be available in the server error log

My .htaccess file is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^finduser/(.*)/(.*)/$ finduser/finduserResult.php?City=$1&txtAreaRzip=$2 [L,NC]
```

hhtpd.conf File:
I have enable the LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so.

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled for apache?

Comment: So what's in the error log?

Comment: check your apache error log, what is it saying?

Comment: Your .htaccess file is fine. Try @MarkoD's suggestion. Consider wrapping your rewrite directives inside IfModule tags: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>`

Answer (score 6):

make sure your wamp rewrite_modue is on..

in APACHE > APACHE Modules > rewrite_module

Answer (score 0):

You need set the following settings:
in htaccess

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

in php script need add

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And you will get error messages

Answer (score 0):

Try do this function

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options All -Indexes
RewriteBase /directoryname/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

other then try do set sh4040 plugin

Answer (score 0):

Please check error log go to the directory cd /var/log/apache2 type ls -->enter. if you have an error .htaccess: Invalid comman$

than have solved this issue by running a command.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
```