# .htaccess 500 error

Tags: php, .htaccess

Whenever I apply .htaccess file, it shows "500 internal sever error".when I put  empty code .htaccess file, it runs perfectly. If I wrote below code, it shows the error.My .htaccess code is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*)/$ user/searchUsrResult.php?selFindUsrCity=$1&txtFindUSrAreaRzip=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: 500 is just the error presented to the client. You need to look in your server logs to find out what the error actually is.

Comment: duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003589/htaccess-500-internal-server-error

Comment: Don't repeat questions if you don't get good answers. (And don't ignore comments on questions that are trying to help you write better questions).

Answer (score 1):

As Carlos mentioned, there is no problem with your RewriteRule, you have mod_wrewrite disabled. If you are using WAMP, you can enable it by editing the httpd.conf by uncommenting the line

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Also like Andrew said, please check you have AllowOverride ALL. Find it by searching the DocumentRoot in httpd.conf and check if it is

```
AllowOverride All
```

within the `<Directory />   </Directory>`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have overrides disabled in your apache config:

```
AllowOverride None
```

try to change it and see if the issue is resolved:

```
AllowOverride All
```

See here for full options for this setting: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

If you're using VHOSTS, you can change this setting inside a  block inside the VHOST block

Comment: Yes. I am using virualhost also. still the error comes. Kindly give  solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with the `RewriteRule`, so the more likely problem is that you do not have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

If you are running Ubuntu or Debian (or any other Debian derivative I suppose) execute (as root or with `sudo`):

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Also, check the `AllowOverride` value as Andrew suggested, but that would just ignore your RewriteRule instead of throwing error 500.